# How to validate domain name using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code for validating domain name.

```
function frmValidate() {
    var val = document.frmDomin;
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/.test(val.name.value)) {
    }
    else {
        alert("Enter Valid Domain Name");
        val.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
<form name="frmDomin" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return frmValidate();">
Domain Name : <input type="text" value="" id="name" name="name"  />
</form>
```

Now I entered `http://devp1.tech.in` and it alert the message. I want to enter sub domain also. How to change this? I should not get alert.

Comment: Show sample input and expected output.

Comment: if you want to validate only the domain names then why are you passing `http://`?

Comment: Including `http://` makes it a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier), not just a domain/host name.

Comment: Two immediate problems that I can see: no support for .co.uk (or subdomains, which your question is about) but also two consecutive hyphens is only valid as part of an IDN.

Comment: You need to add a dot iniside the character class. `^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that regex allow two dots in a row for subdomains, like  subdomain..google.es. Can you fix it ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/KByADagF3Z)

Comment: Can you update this answer to also allow subdomains  ?

Comment: Something missing here, It doesn't match `www.test2.com` but it does match `test2.com`.

Comment: it does not test for domain in numbers like 192.168.3.1

Comment: In my implementation of this answer, it worked as `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+/` regex

Comment: Why aren't underscores included in regex?

Comment: @MiguelMota Underscore is no allowed characters in domain names.

Comment: This regex does not work correctly. It should match all samples given here except the last one which is no valid domain: https://regex101.com/r/Vi2CYC/1 But it fails to match 3 valid domains and does match the invalid one at the end. For comparison, this one works as expected: https://regex101.com/r/d7YuFt/1

Comment: This also fails for single-letter domains, i.e. `a.co`, but those are valid.

Answer (score 15):

This is a little on the heavy side:

```
^(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-z\-]+)\:\/{1,3})?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9])(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]){1,61}(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+|\[(?:(?:(?:[a-fA-F0-9]){1,4})(?::(?:[a-fA-F0-9]){1,4}){7}|::1|::)\]|(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}))(?:\:[0-9]{1,5})?$
```

Will match:

- `google.com`
- `db.my-website.co.us`
- `ftp://container-617.databases.online`
- `many-ports.com:7777`

Note: will *not* match `localhost`

IPv4

- `192.168.3.1`
- `127.0.0.1:3306`

IPv6 (partial support)

- `[2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334]`
- `[2001:db8:85a3:0:0:8a2e:370:7334]` (same as previous)
- `[da7a:ba5e:da7a:ba5e:da7a:ba5e:da7a:ba5e]:3306`
- `[::1]` (localhost loopback)
- `[::]` (unspecified address)

But not (IPv6)

- [`2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334]`

This regular expression does not support collapsing consecutive 0-segments into a '::' in IPv6 addresses. (read: don't try this on IPv6 addresses)

Comment: 2 letter domains such as `ti.com` do not work with this regex.

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr.Should be fixed? In all honesty, I'm no longer 100% sure what most of that regex does anyway...

Answer (score 11):

I'd advise reading up on O'Reilly's guide: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch08s15.html

Try using https://regex101.com/ to validate the results of your regex.

> 8.15. Validating Domain Names Problem You want to check whether a string looks like it may be a valid, fully qualified domain name, or
> find such domain names in longer text.
>
> Solution Check whether a string looks like a valid domain name:
>
> ```
> ^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}$
> ```
>
> Regex options: Case insensitive Regex flavors: .NET, Java, JavaScript,
> PCRE, Perl, Python
>
> ```
> \A([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}\Z
> ```
>
> Regex options: Case insensitive Regex flavors: .NET, Java, PCRE, Perl,
> Python, Ruby Find valid domain names in longer text:
>
> ```
> \b([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}\b
> ```
>
> Regex options: Case insensitive Regex flavors: .NET, Java, JavaScript,
> PCRE, Perl, Python, Ruby Check whether each part of the domain is not
> longer than 63 characters:
>
> ```
> \b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b
> ```
>
> Regex options: Case insensitive Regex flavors: .NET, Java, JavaScript,
> PCRE, Perl, Python, Ruby Allow internationalized domain names using
> the punycode notation:
>
> ```
> \b((xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}\b
> ```
>
> Regex options: Case insensitive Regex flavors: .NET, Java, JavaScript,
> PCRE, Perl, Python, Ruby Check whether each part of the domain is not
> longer than 63 characters, and allow internationalized domain names
> using the punycode notation:
>
> ```
> \b((?=[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.)(xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,63}\b
> ```
>
> Regex options: Case insensitive Regex flavors: .NET, Java, JavaScript,
> PCRE, Perl, Python, Ruby
>
> **Discussion**
> A domain name has the form of domain.tld, or subdomain.domain.tld, or any number of additional subdomains. ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function frmValidate() {
        var val = document.frmDomin.name.value;
        if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$/.test(val)) {
            alert("Valid Domain Name");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Enter Valid Domain Name");
            val.name.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note : This will not validate Url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the IGNORECASE flag turned on:

`[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)+`

Requires at least one '.' surrounded by alnums, and allows any number of '-' surrounded by alnums.