# Extract web url from text using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to combine 
[`/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/` from [How to validate domain name using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093545/how-to-validate-domain-name-using-regex) (this works only for single words not text)] 
 and 
 [`/(\b(((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|(ww.\.))[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig` from [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript) (this works for text)] 
 into a single regex. 
 
 
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect URLs in text with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500260/detect-urls-in-text-with-javascript)

Comment: @noob - I have already referenced the link in my original question

Comment: How do you want the answer to differ from the second regexp you mentioned?

Comment: @LarsH The second regex does not match `lkmo.co.pl` (or `google.com`), it does match `http://lkmo.co.pl` (or `https://google.com`). Would like to add this aspect to the second regex

Comment: So, by "combine" you mean that you want a regex that matches everything that the first one matches, as well as everything that the second one matches? Then you want `(A)|(B)`, where A and B are the two regexes. Alternatively, you could put `?` before the first `[` in the second regex: `/(\b(((https?|ftp|file):\/\/)|(ww.\.))?[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig`

Comment: @LarsH - thanks for the comment, it worked :)