# Regex for url validation with some matching pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex for validate url through Javascript. So here the samples of urls that I want to be validated

https://www.google.com

https://google.com

http://www.google.com

http://google.com

google.com

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

So to achieve that I have made the regex like this

`^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`

But its not matching all the patterns what I have shared. So can someone tell me what exactly the regex should be like?

No restriction should be there in the domain name. It might come with  .in, .edu, .xyz, .com etc.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410311/regular-expression-for-url-validation-in-javascript or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093545/how-to-validate-domain-name-using-regex/38578855)

Comment: @anubhava any domain name it should be like .in, .edu, .xyz, .com etc. No restriction should be there.

Comment: That works fine but the thing is it is also validating this one
`www.dgsds.com.ccxx` which is an invalid url.

Comment: What is definition of invalid URL here? I guess you will need exhaustive list of top domains to validate your domain.

Comment: I am not telling about the list. The url should be max 2 dots(.), more than 2 dots in an url should be an invalid one I think.

Comment: So `www.bbc.co.uk` will be invalid?

Comment: Ok max 2-3 is fine. As I see in the url what you have shared seems to a valid one. But more than that doesn't look like a valid url.

Comment: Try this: `/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{1,3}$/gmi`

Comment: How about making use of the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) which already has it all?

Comment: https://regexr.com/5pj1t

Comment: ... and maybe [`/(?:https*:\/\/)*(?:www\.)*[^.\s\/]+(?:\.[^.\s\/]+)/`versus `/(?:https*:\/\/)*(?:www\.)*[^.\s\/]+(?:\.[^.\s\/]+)+/`](https://regex101.com/r/fI0KLf/1/) for a very rough first plausibility check.

Comment: Sorry, you say your regex does not match the URLs you posted, but it [does match them](https://regex101.com/r/dZpWSE/1). So, what is the issue?